# Flow Iterable type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to define a **zip** function in javascript with flow types added to it.

The types I have for now are the following:

```
export function *zip<T>(...iterables:Array<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<Array<T>> {
   const iterators = iterables.map(iterable => iter(iterable));
   while(true){
      const items = iterators.map(iterator => iterator.next());
      if (items.some(item => item.done)){
         return;
      }
      yield items.map(item => item.value);
  }
}

function *iter<T>(iterable:Iterable<T>): Iterator<T> {
   yield* iterable;
}
```

The error flow (0.64) gives me is on the `return;` line and it says:

```
Generator
This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
$Iterable: tools/misc.js:182
Property `@@iterator` is incompatible:
function type: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_38c3acbb/core.js:508
This type is incompatible with
function type: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_38c3acbb/core.js:503
```

The [example in flow's documentation](https://flow.org/blog/2015/11/09/Generators/) looks very similar so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Any suggestion concerning the types (or even the code itself) is also welcome.

**Edit** The error on flow version 0.92.1 is:

> Cannot return undefined because undefined is incompatible with `T` in array element of type argument `Yield` of the return value of property `@@iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on zip generator return type, it is expected to yield values of type `Array<T>`.
However, `yield items.map(item => item.value);` produces `Array<void | T>`, since each `item` in that map callback is `IteratorResult<T, void>`. So there's a type mismatch between actual and expected yield value.

That being said, you are already checking your items with:

```
if (items.some(item => item.done)){
   return;
}
```

, so by the time execution reaches `yield` none of the item values can be `undefined`. Unfortunately Flow can't figure it out on its own. But we can force it into type casting that value:

```
 export function *zip<T>(...iterables:Array<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<Array<T>> {
   const iterators = iterables.map(iterable => iter(iterable));
   while(true){
      const items = iterators.map(iterator => iterator.next());
      if (items.some(item => item.done)){
         return;
      }
      yield ((items.map(item => { return item.value }): Array<any>): Array<T>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense. I was too focused on the `return` because the error was pointing explicitly to this line. I've updated flow to see it the error was any better (from 0.64 to 0.92.1). The new error I had for this mistake was:

Cannot return undefined because undefined [1] is incompatible with `T` [2] in array element of type argument `Yield` [3] of the return value of property `@@iterator`. 

Which looks way better, moral of this story, I should update before asking next time.